# Simulating Hierarchical Data

Tags: multilevel-analysis, simulation, synthetic-data

I want to simulate a dataset that has a "grand mean", and then group means (with some deviation from the grand mean). Nevertheless, I have a bit of a problem conceptualising the problem: if I want (e.g.) the "grand mean" to be $\mu$ = 2, and then $\mu_{group1}$ = 1.5, and $\mu_{group2}$ = 2.5. Is it possible to somehow impose the constraint that $\mu$ still equals 2? What if the groups have unequal sizes?

Or am I thinking about it in a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, I think, the use of terminology and notation. Notation is defined within the framework of a model. You can have a model
$$
Y_{ij}=\mu+\delta_j+\epsilon_{ij},\ \sum_{j=1}^J\delta_j=0,
$$
where $\mu=2$ is what you call "grand mean", $J=2$ is the number of groups, $\delta_j$ the group effect for group $j$, these adding up to zero, i.e., -0.5 and 0.5 in your example, $\epsilon_{ij}$ the i.i.d. random error of observation $i=1,\ldots,N_j$ in group $j$ with $N_j$ observations.

There's nothing wrong with simulating from this model if the $N_j$ are not all equal, and the value $\mu$ is what it's defined to be ($\mu=2$ here) in any case.

However you are right observing that the expected value of the mean of the data sampled from such a model will not be $\mu$ unless $N_1=N_2$. So $\mu$ may not deserve to be called "grand mean" then (a terminology which I believe comes from designs where the group sizes are all the same). It's still $\mu$ though.

Ultimately you have to decide what you want: Data with $\mu=2$ in the model above, or data for which the expected value of the sample mean is 2, which requires different parameter choices in case the group sizes are not equal.

Comment: Thanks! This clears things up. Looking at the model definitely makes the conceptualisation easier. I should've done in in the first place :)